# Perl script can't unzip to mounted Windows share - permission denied

Tags: perl, permissions, smb

I have a simple script that is unzipping a file to a mounted Windows share.  It is normally launched as a Postfix alias when a new email arrives, but even when I run it as root I get a permission denied error.

The script is doing this:

```
if ( </tmp/*.zip> ){
        unzip '</tmp/*.zip>' => '</mnt/win/#1.txt>'
                or die "unzip failed: $UnzipError\n";
}
```

As root I can copy files to /mnt/win without a problem, but when this script is launched by Postfix it fails with permission denied.

/etc/fstab looks like:

```
//srvr1/tmp /mnt/win  cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=iso8859-1,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

ls -ld looks like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 196608 Jul 15 17:24 /mnt/win
```

Files produced by the script are nobody/nogroup, but I'm not sure how I change the permissions of /mnt/win to allow nobody/nogroup to read/write.

```
cmhod -R ugo+RW /mnt/win
```

Also gives permission denied. Is there a way to change permissions in /etc/fstab to allow nobody/nogroup?

Comment: What module does your `unzip` come from?  Are you really trying to unzip a file named `</mnt/win/#1.txt>`?

Comment: unzip comes from `IO::Uncompress::unzip` - and there's a parameter in that command that adds the file name at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this command to change the permissions of folder & files inside it.

```
sudo chmod -R R+X /mnt/win
```

If you want to change the user of the file as well which is `nobody/nogroup` rightnow, you can use this commands :

```
sudo chown -R username.username /mnt/win/
```

Here you can choose any user's name e.g. mine is `mukesh`

```
sudo chown -R mueksh.mukesh /mnt/win/
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of these worked.. permission denied for each as I've been getting.  I actually tried chmod first.

Comment: `root@server:/home/user# sudo chmod -R R+X /mnt/win
chmod: invalid mode: âR+Xâ
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
root@server:/home/user# sudo chown -R nobody.nogroup /mnt/win
chown: changing ownership of â/mnt/winâ: Permission denied`

Comment: I think you mean `chmod -R a+rx`, which adds the read and execute bits for user, group and other.